# Best approach for "Fade in/fadeout" menu bar on mouse over

Tags: javascript, html, css

First off, my apologies for a lengthy post. I am trying to use CSS, HTML and JavaScript, so please don't recommend using std. libraries.

1)I have  found people using different approaches in CSS,HTML and JavaScript  to achieve the "fade in/ fade out effect" on navigation bars, some of the approaches using CSS and JavaScript are:

a) Use property "left" to get the submenu outside the screen. Default left :-500px ;onmouseover-  left:-10px

b) Use property "visibility". Default visibility: "hidden" and onmouseover- 
visibility: visbile

c)use property "display". Default  display:none and onmouseover- display:block

My question is which one is the best approach and why?

2)I have used the method a) in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/A7TND/.

**CSS**

```
.teal-box{
left:-10px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="level1" onmouseover="showSubs(&quot;+&quot;)">
```

**Javascript**

```
switch (vwFlg){    
case "+" :
elmt.style.left = "-10px";
...
}
```

In the example, I am not sure whether the function gets called over and over when I am moving between the main item(favorite) and subitems(jsfiddle, google), my questions are:
 a) does it get called over and over during the mouse movement between main items(favorites) and sub-items(google and jsfiddle)?
b) how does that(calling javascript function over and over) affect  the responsiveness of the page?

3.The approach I did for having multiple images(see the jsfiddle link) separated by

---

, is have multiple divs - where  top has different values, is that the best approach? This would mean , I would have to write a div for each image, is there a some spiffy way of using "position" properties  absolute and relative to achieve that without creating as many divs as images?

4. I want to have a table [image: Table with row selectors],how do I get that "button popping out of the page" look ? I tried to debug a commercial web app, it seems they seem to repeat a background image, which I tried, but that did not work.

**CSS**

```
.sel-row {
border-style:solid;
border-width:1px;
background-image:url("\lb_sel.gif");
background-repeat:repeat-x-y;
background-color:#CDD2D7 ;
border-color:#8B96A2 ;
height:20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach for something like this, is to have the hidden element be a child of the hover element, then use absolute positioning + display for the hide/show

```
<li>
  Button Copy
  <span>HIDE SHOW ME</span>
</li>

li {
  position:relative;
}
li:hover span {
  display:block;
}
li span {
  position:absolute;
  top:25px;
  left:0;
  display:none;
}
```

Are you animating the opacity as well?

Use javascript to add a class to the element, CSS3 to animate but understand the browsers that don't use CSS3. Also, don't use display anymore.

```
<li>
      Button Copy
      <span>HIDE SHOW ME</span>
    </li>

    li {
      position:relative;
    }
    li.show span {
      opacity:0;
    }
    li span {
      position:absolute;
      top:25px;
      left:0;
      opacity:1;
      -webkit-transition: all .8s ease-in;
      -moz-transition: all .8s ease-in;
      -o-transition: all .8s ease-in;
      -ms-transition: all .8s ease-in;
      transition: all .8s ease-in;
    }
```

With a browser that doesn't support css3, I use Modernizr + jQuery for the fallback. You'd have to turn this into a toggle.

```
if (!Modernizr.csstransitions) { // if browser doesn't support css3.transitions
  $('li span').animate({ "opacity": '1' }, 800);
} else { // if browser does support css3.transitions
  $('li').addClass('show');
}
```

Comment: @ Jason, thx. for the response. So, you are using the 1.c that I mentioned in my question - basically display:none  for li  and display:block for li:hover span. is there any advantages of using display manipulation over  hidden manipulation or using left manipulation?

Comment: Short answer: hidden only hides the element, but it still exists on the page, so it could affect hover effects of anything living behind it. Display will make it act like it's not on the page, but you can't animate display. Display has no effect on hover status of anything else. Position left works just as well, except I've found it a little trickier to work with because sometimes the element will appear when you didn't plan on it and if you are moving it off the left of the screen, the browser still draws it, so it takes up some processor power.

Comment: Was that short? </sarcasm> http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp

Comment: Thx. Jason! Much shorter than my long question, so yes it is short;-)